# Handle button interrupts in button kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am writing a button module for linux kernel 4.1 on freescale iMX6 quad

```
 # cat /proc/interrupts
                CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3
    173:          0          0          0          0  gpio-mxc   7 Edge      PB_RIGHT
    176:          0          0          0          0  gpio-mxc  10 Edge      PB_YESOK
    231:          0          0          0          0  gpio-mxc  31 Edge      PB_LEFT
```

I have used request_irq() function to receive interrupts on buttons like LEFT ,RIGHT , YESOK. like mentioned below

```
ret = request_irq(173,     /* The interrupt number requested */
                 (irq_handler_t) gpioirqhandler, /* The pointer to the handler function below */
                 IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING,         /* Use the custom kernel param to set interrupt type */
                 "PB_RIGHT",  /* Used in /proc/interrupts to identify the owner */
                  NULL);
```

I am getting this error while loading this module and hence module is not getting loaded.

```
genirq: Flags mismatch irq 173. 00000001 (PB_RIGHT) vs. 00000083 (PB_RIGHT)
Error request IRQ 173
 - code -16 , EIO 5 , EINVAL 22
```

Need help to understand and fix this issue!

Thanks

Comment: I guess the driver is ported from lower version to newer kernel. I suggest to understand the required flag settings for this driver. Actually error comes from here http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/manage.c?v=4.1#L1272

Comment: What you are trying to do is a bad way of doing it, specifying the IRQ number yourself in the request_irq call. Why not use the existing gpio-keys driver by binding a gpio to it from device tree and then generate appropriate key event by specifying the keycode.